# Remove 1 day from date

Tags: vb.net

I have the date working fine, and I know how to remove a date when doing it one way. But, I need the date in a special format, so I am trying to figure out how to remove 1 day from it with the following code:

```
TDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd")
Ydate.Text = Datetime.Now.ToString("MM/dd")
```

How can I remove 1 day from the Ydate.text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AddDay(-1)

so 
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("MM/dd")

Comment: Both options answers worked perfectly. I will mark you as the answer due to you were first. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To remove one day use the AddDays function with a negative number.

```
Dim _today As Date = Date.Now
Dim _yesterday = _today.AddDays(-1)
```

Your example:

```
Ydate.Text = Datetime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("MM/dd")
```

Comment: See?  Thats what you get for taking the time to format your code - you lose the accept.  That should teach you!  ;)

Comment: I usually pick an answer that has better details or examples, not just the first one. @Plutonix.